# Trying to construct an IF statement in Excel with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

Basically I need to calculate a column that sum's previous columns only if:

- The number in column Q > 4,
- Column S = 'N'   (its  a 'Y' or 'N' flag in this column and I only want to sum if there is an 'N'
- P != 0 (There is a number in column P.)

This is the incorrect statement which I came up with:

=IF((Q2>4) AND (S2='N') AND (P2 != 0), V2)

(Column V contains the calculation I want to make, given that these conditions are met.

Kinda lost here guys, would really appreciate any help.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** fixed single-quote>>double and `!=` >> `<>`

```
=IF(AND(Q2>4, S2="N", P2<>0), V2, "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim! Unfortunately Excel says it found a problem with the formula. Any ideas?

Comment: This might be more robust for the P column:
IF(AND(Q2>4, S2='N', ISNUMBER(P2)), V2, "")

When I don't feel like error checking all fields, and I know that any error should be a null or zero answer I often do the following:

IFERROR(IF(AND(Q2>4, S2='N', ISNUMBER(P2)), V2, ""),"")

Comment: I got an error again with both formulae. Not too sure what it could be, the logic seems accurate to me. :( Thanks for all the help though I really appreciate it.

Comment: Turns out it only needed double quotes around 'N'! instead of 'N', "N"...Thanks for the help!!

Comment: My bad - missed the single-quote. Thx for the correction @pnuts